# insert form data with PDO not work

Tags: php, validation, pdo

I have a multipage form for which I would like to use sessions to store field values, in each page doing some validation and  and at the end collect values from all pages and store the in DB.I used [This tutorial](http://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/#comment-117215), but I would like to use PDO instead of Mysql. Could someone help me to know what is the problem with this code and why it insert nothing in DB?

This is the php code to insert data into db:

```
<?php
session_start();

try{
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Application;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'user', 'mypass');

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25) VALUES (:q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :q5, :q6, :q7, :q8, :q9, :q10, :q11, :q12, :q13, :q14, :q15, :q16, :q17, :q18, :q19, :q20, :q21, :q22, :q23, :q24, :q25)');

    $stmt->execute(array(':q1' => $q1,':q2' => $q2, ':q3' => $q3, ':q4' => $q4, ':q5' => $q5, ':q6' => $q6, ':q7' => $q7, ':q8' => $q8, ':q9' => $q9, ':q10' => $q10, ':q11' => $q11, ':q12' => $q12, ':q13' => $q13, ':q14' => $q14, ':q15' => $q15, ':q16' => $q16, ':q17' => $q17, ':q18' => $q18, ':q19' => $q19, ':q20' => $q20, ':q21' => $q21, ':q22' => $q22, ':q23' => $q23, ':q24' => $q24, ':q25' => $q25));

     }

 catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
   }

   header('Location: Thankyou.php');
   exit;
?>
```

and this is the code for last page of my form:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['q25'])) {
 if (!empty($_SESSION['post'])){
 if (empty($_POST['productionCountry2'])
 || empty($_POST['q24'])
 || empty($_POST['q25'])){

 // Setting error for page 5.
  $_SESSION['error_page5'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
 header("location: page5.php"); // Redirecting to fifth page.
 } else {

 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
  } 

 extract($_SESSION['post']); // Function to extract array.

   include('insertData.php');  //the php file which insert data into db

 unset($_SESSION['post']); // Destroying session.*/

  }  

  } else {
       header("location: page1.php"); // Redirecting to first page.
 }
  } else {
       header("location: page1.php"); // Redirecting to first page.
 }

 ?>


 <html>
 <head>

 <title>Survey Form</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html: charset=UTF-8" />

 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');

   background:
              linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)),
              url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');

   text-align: center;  
   margin-top: 300px;
   font-size: 200%;
 } 

 </style>
 </head>

 <body>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** This is the code related to dropdown list (question 5 in the form)

```
   <html>
   <fieldset id = "q5"> <legend class="Q5"></legend>
   <span>  Where were you born?</span><span>*</span>
   <div class="fieldset content">
   <p> 
   <?php

   include('newCountry.php');
    ?>

   <select name="q5[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px"> 

   <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $line['country'];?>"> <?php echo $line['country'];?>      </option>  
   <?php 
    } 
   ?>
   </select> 
   </p>
   </div> 
   </fieldset>
   </html>
```

Comment: Maybe replacing `Exception` with `PDOException`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: 1. your `unset($_SESSION...)` won't be called on a successful InsertData 2. can you please add a `die;` before `header('Location: Thankyou.php');` and tell us if there are any messages on screen?

Comment: @STTLCU: I did, this is the message: Exception -> string(80) "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'q5' cannot be null"

Comment: P.S q5 is "where were u born" with a dropdown list of countries

Comment: `$q5` is empty. Check if you have all the inputs you need. also, add the comment in your answer, because it's relevant

Comment: @STTLCU: sorry I dont unserstand why $q5 is empty? I fill it in the form (I mean I select a country) so why is it empty? :(

Comment: @mOna, do the `print_r($_POST)` or `$_SESSION` to view submitted/stored values

Comment: @RamSharma: Do u mean s.th like this? $_SESSION['q4'] = $_POST['q4'];
$_SESSION['q5'] = implode(',', $_POST['birthplace']); (should I do it in each of my pages? or I can just write all of them (from q1-q25) in my last page or insertData php file?

Comment: No, just do print_r on that page where you are not getting value

Comment: @RamSharma: this is the message when I wrote print_r($_POST): Array ( [q1] => male [q2] => under 18 [q3] => married [q4] => yes [birthplace] => Array ( [0] => Angola ) [countrylived] => Array ( [0] => Angola ) [q7] => doctoral degree [submit1] => Submit Form1 )

Comment: I think the problem is only related to dropdown list of countries..but I dont know wht should i do .

Comment: @mOna, you don't have q5 variable here

Comment: @RamSharma: Maybe I have to add the condition to check if the posted value is array after this line: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {... //CHECK ID POSTED IS ARRAY, if yes, Implode it ...//) am I correct? the problem is that I don't know how to check if the posted value is array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drop down box name is birthplace change it to `q5` to get the data in `q5` variable or assign `birthplace` to `q5`.

I am also suspected about `q6` variable. Change the drop down box `countrylived` name to q6 or assign `countrylived` to `q6`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved the problem partially, I mean now the data are inserted into DB, but the answers related to question 5,6, 8 and other questions which are array are inserted into db as "Array" instead of their value!

Comment: I feel I had to use implode for these types!?

Comment: We generally use implode with multiple values or arrays

Comment: I added this: $q5 = implode(',', $_POST['q5']);
$q6 = implode(',', $_POST['q6']); before validation check of the first page and wrote empty($q5) instead of empty($_POST['q5']), but still does not work! :(

Comment: @mOna, please share your drop down field code. I feel, you have something wrong with that also

Comment: but this problem is not only for dropdown, but also for auto completions (wherever there is array).. that's why I thought maybe I had to use implode.. however if u think it is needed I will edit my post, should I?

Comment: change name `q5[]` to `q5`

Comment: but user has te be able to have multiple selection, so if I change it to q5, if user select 2 countries from drop down, then only the last one will be shown by print_r($_POST).. _:(

Comment: in that case check if it's array than implode it and assign to $q5

Comment: Thanks for yr help, Finally Done :) I added this: if (is_array($_POST[$key])){
   $_SESSION['post'][$key] = implode(',', $_POST[$key]); else{ ... and it worked :)